# Is there a difference between reduced major axis regression and ranged major axis regression?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm hoping this is an easy semantic question. I've been asked to calculate p values for a "reduced major axis" regression.

A [search reveals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673012/obtaining-regression-coefficients-from-reduced-major-axis-regression-models-usin)
which states "I'm using a reduced major axis regression with R's lmodel2 package". However, the lmodel2 documentation says nothing about "reduced major axis" and only refers to "ranged major axis" regression. Presumably, "reduced" and "ranged" mean the same thing, but presumptions are dangerous. I have searched high and low (well, for more than an hour - does that count?) for a answer to whether the R in RMA means both "reduced" and "ranged", but I'm none the wiser. I would be very grateful for an answer, if anyone is feeling authoritative...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a statistic question and not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ed, I had the same question and found these sites which state that SMA and reduced major axis are the same in R:

http://strata.uga.edu/8370/lecturenotes/regression.html
http://hompal-stats.wabarr.com/homework_assignment_5.html

This convention apparently arises from Legendre and Legendre 1998:

https://www.unc.edu/courses/2007spring/biol/145/001/docs/lectures/Nov5.html

That's the best I can do for you!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same challenge.
Reduced Major Axis (RMA) regression is same as Standard Major Axis (SMA) regression in the lmodel2 package in R statistical software.

In addition to the links @Steve sent you could also check out:

Article on Reduced Major Axis Regression By William V. Harper (http://twin.sci-hub.tw/6617/b615c5cebc733901b3cf9a812baaa269/harper2016.pdf), and

https://influentialpoints.com/Training/errors-in-variables_regression-principles-properties-assumptions.htm#orth